# What level of maths do I need for artificial intelligence?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pattern-recognition, mathematical-foundations

I want to learn maths for artificial intelligence. I heard that main areas of mathematics for AI are Multivariable Calculus, Linear Algebra, Probability and Statistics and Discrete Mathematics. But what level of these subjects do I need? For example the easy level is like Calculus of Gilbert Strang and 18.01 Calculus from MIT Open Course Ware. The hard level is Apostol's or Spivak's Calculus. Do I need easy level of maths or hard level to be good at artificial intelligence and its areas (machine learning, pattern recognition).

Comment: The best possible level. But if you succeed, you can forget it all. The computer will do it for you. You probably cannot learn everything that might be useful, and there are many ways of solving problems. If you look for example at natural language processing, some people are betting on statistics and others on algebraic approaches. The answer is probably a mix of that, and much more. And some of it is not so simple (probabilistic grammars are sometimes less obvious than would seem). In many respects AI encompasses too much to be much more than a buzzword.

Comment: "you can forget it all" -- my impression of the AI and ML fields are that exactly this is a huge problem they (read: many of the hype-followers) have: lots of applying things, little understanding how it works.

Comment: But I want understand! And maybe one day I want to become a researcher in this area.

Comment: As a grad student studying probabilistic graph models, I've found probability is relatively important, discrete math is also relevant, calculus and linear algebra I haven't found it as important. It largely depends on the particular domain you're intending to study what is important, but I'd recommend going for the highest level you can. You're never going to get to a problem and say "Man, if only I hadn't learned that advanced calculus this would be so much easier...", and you might just notice "Hey this is just an applied version of that one property"